# cannot compile JsWorker for camunda modulator using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to deploy a jsworker for Camunda Modulator but when I compile my js file using node I get the following error:

```bash
$ nodejs ./CheckRequestFeasibilityWorker.js
(node:27539) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `nodejs --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/JsWorkers/CheckRequestFeasibilityWorker/CheckRequestFeasibilityWorker.js:1
import { Client, logger } from "camunda-external-task-client-js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.15.0
```

I have installed the `camunda-external-task-client-js`  package using npm

here's my code:

```js
import { Client, logger } from "camunda-external-task-client-js";

// configuration for the Client:
//  - 'baseUrl': url to the Process Engine
//  - 'logger': utility to automatically log important events
const config = { baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest", use: logger };

// create a Client instance with custom configuration
const client = new Client(config);

// susbscribe to the topic: 'check-request-feasibility'
client.subscribe("check-request-feasibility", async function({ task, taskService }) {
  // Put your business logic
  var Is_feasible = math.random() >= 0.5;
  const processVariables = new Variables();
  processVariables.set("Is_feasible",Is_feasible);
  // complete the task
  await taskService.complete(task);
});
```